# Month of previous year doesnt go away when selecting a new year Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-datasource

I have two slicers in my report. Year and 12 months. 
If I look at the data by selecting year only, months are changing fine, according to year.

[image]

[image]

But if I choose Year 2017 and, lets say, December month, and then switch to Year 2018 - it will display two months of December at the end of the Month slicer.

Looks fine so far:

[image]

Choosing another year:

[image: ,]

Is it some kind of a bug?
I am expecting it to switch to `Dec 2018` if i switch a Year.

Data structure:

[image]

Link to .ipbx file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/qo0hl1a6vulx0bf/User%20Open%20Closed%20Tasks.pbix?dl=0

Comment: Can you share your data structure? There are a number of things that could contribute to this, and without seeing the data structure, it's almost impossible to tell.

Comment: Joe, I updated. Thank you

Comment: That is expected. Slicer selections are not cleared automatically as with other kind of visuals. Slicers display filtered values plus active selections.

Answer (score 0):

Value for column Month displaying Month name and current year: `Jan 2017`. So I changed column Month to display just a `month Name`, without year and it works.